# Windows 10 and Condusiv's expresscache

Tags: windows-10, windows-10-upgrade, hard-drive-cache, hp-envy

Has anyone been able to get their [ExpressCache](https://www.condusiv.com/partners/oem/technologies/expresscache/) working with Windows 10? I've tried to reinstall but ECCMD still says the driver could not be found. I'm using an HP Envy desktop. I've seen some activity about this on the lenovo forum as well as the HP forum, but I wanted to check if anyone here was able to get this to work.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: I eventually decided I didn't really believe in the ExpressCache stuff.  So I dedicated the device to ReadyBoost (using the tab on the drive properties Window) at let Windows get on with it.

Answer (score 1):

I have a 2 year old Samsung Series 7 Chronos 700Z5C Notebook - it came with an 8GB SSD with ExpressCache (verison 1.0.94 which Samsung have never updated).  When I upgraded to Windows 10, the upgrade did not carry ExpressCache forward - it was not installed in the upgraded system.

Attempts to run the installer failed, rejected by Windows 10.

Samsung support (UK) say "What we can advise you is that we are already aware of this and we'll make sure to provide an update using our website the soonest possible time."  Samsung US have a note saying ExpressCache is not supported for Windows 10(!).  Some other manufacturers have provided updates.

I removed the registry entry in HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\AppCompatFlags\UpgradeCompatibility blocking the installation and then the original (Samsung-provided) ExpressCache 1.0.94 for earlier Windows releases installed fine, and works much as before as far as I can tell from the results of the eecmd -info command.  At least nothing has obviously gone wrong yet.  Your mileage may differ.

I've read some hints suggesting that there is some conflict between MS and Condusiv about compatibility/signing, but I don't know.  You can hope for a new release from Samsung, but my experience of Samsung products means I don't hold out much hope - their software and its support seems of a fairly low quality.

Answer (score 0):

I've read where some have been able to get it to work, while others have not. I've tried almost all of the solutions from other users and cannot get it to work either. Since ExpressCache is a 3rd party software licensed solely to OEM companies like HP, any files needed to upgrade for windows 10 need to come from HP.

I've contacted support via telephone and the forums and they are aware of the issue. If/when they have a fix it will (and according to support) only be rolled out to recent purchased of their hardware. It's licensing issue.

In the meantime, I went ahead and purchased a Samsung 850 EVO 500GB SSD Drive and replaced the hard drive that came with my HP and my speeds and performance are even better than when ExpressCache was working with Windows 8.1.

IF that is not an option and you really need ExpressCache, I would suggest going back to the version of windows that it worked on. And call support and let them know about your issues. The more we call the faster they will respond.

Answer (score 0):

Please try the latest version (1.3.118) from Lenovo: [32bit](http://support.lenovo.com/us/en/downloads/ds104445) or [64 bit](http://support.lenovo.com/us/en/downloads/ds104444). This will probably work. Make sure you uninstall the previous version and reboot before installing.

Answer (score 0):

First you have to backup your old (HP OEM) license of the Condusiv ExpressCache Software. The filename is `EC.LMF` and it is located inside the `C:\Windows.old\Program Files\Condusiv Technologies\ExpressCache` directory.

Next you can use the above supplied Lenovo installer to install the ExpressCache (v1.3.118) software,  make sure to overwrite the existing `EC.LMF` after installation with the one you made backup from in previous step otherwise you will get a `Product is not licensed to run on this system` error.

[Reference](http://h30434.www3.hp.com/t5/Desktop-Operating-Systems-Software-Recovery/ExpressCache-not-working-with-Windows-10/m-p/5226941#M113943)